# in php how to download Image and at the same time display that image in browser using header?

Tags: php, image, download, header

I am applying watermark to the image using php where after uploading the image the fixed watermark gets glued to the image and in the last I can able to display the image or I can able to download the image but I want to do both the things at the same time

this code shows me the image at the last

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($new_canvas, NULL , 90);
```

this code download the image at the last

```
header('Content-Disposition: Attachment;filename=image.jpeg');
            imagejpeg($new_canvas, NULL , 90);
```

but I am not able to do both the things together?

I tried this but no result

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
 header('Content-Disposition: Attachment;filename=image.jpeg');
                imagejpeg($new_canvas, NULL , 90);
```

Comment: You can't set multiple different headers like that.  You are probably going to need 2 files.. ..display the image using a standard `<img>` tag with a link around it and link to a second file that downloads the image.  Then you can set the appropriate headers on each file.

Comment: how can i display that image using <img> tag cause i am not saving that image on server side.

Comment: You can encode images using base64. See https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/